# What does this Code mean? (Train Test Split Scikitlearn)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, evaluation

Everywhere I go I see this code. Need help understanding this.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,testsize = 0.20)
```

what does X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test mean in this context which should I put in fit() and predict()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation says, what `train_test_split` does is: `Splits arrays or matrices into random train and test subsets`. You can find it here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html. I believe the right keyword argument is `test_size` instead of `testsize` and it `represents the proportion of the dataset to include in the test split` if it is float or `the absolute number of test samples` if is is an int.
X and y are the `sequence of indexables with same length / shape[0]`, so basically the arrays/lists/matrices/dataframes to be split.

So, all in all, the code splits X and y into random train and test subsets (X_train and X_test for X and y_train and y_test for y). Each test subset should contain 20% of the original array entries as test samples.
You should pass the `_train` subsets to `fit()` and the `_test` subsets to `predict()`. Hope this helps~

Comment: so "x_train" is training labels and x_test training target? this should make y_train test labels and "y test" test target. is this correct?

Comment: What do the original X and y each contain? If X contains the observations and y the equivalent labels, then X_train is the subset of observations used for training and y_train their corresponding labels. The same is true for X_test and y_test.

Comment: original X contain features and Y contain labels(which you want to predict)

Comment: X = training labels example(colour,size,taste) and y = training targets for example(fruit)

Comment: So yeah, as I said in the previous comment after modifying it: X_train is the subset of observations/features used for training and y_train their corresponding labels. The same is true for X_test and y_test. So, to train your model you use X_train as the features and y_train as the ground truth. Similarly, when testing you use X_test as the features and y_test to validate the predicted labels.

Comment: Your last comment was the answer i was looking for. im new to this so I was little confused. thanks

Comment: I am glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, `train_test_split` divides your dataset into training dataset and validation dataset.

The validation set is used to evaluate a given model.

So in this case validation dataset gives us idea about model performance.

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,testsize = 0.20)`

The above line splits the data into 4 parts

1. X_train  - training dataset
2. y_train  - o/p of training dataset
3. X_test   - validation dataset
4. y_test   - o/p of validation dataset

and `testsize = 0.2` means you'll have 20% validation data and 80% training data

Answer (score 1):

`Basically this code split your data into two part.

1. is used for training
2. is for testing

And with the help of the test_size variable you can set the size of testing data

After dividing data into two part you have to fit training data into your model with fit() method.
`